# PreparedStatement SetString doesn't work (case Oracle)

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I don't have an idea why this method gets an error

```
public TdPegawai getTdPegawai(String nip) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        TdPegawai tp = new TdPegawai();
        sql = "select * "
              "from TD_PEGAWAI " + 
              "where NIP=? "; 
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, nip);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            // tp.setblablabla();
        }
        rs.close();

        return tp;
    } finally {
        ConnectionUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
    }
}
```

My SQL variable just returns `SELECT * FROM TD_PEGAWAI WHERE NIP=?`

My nip variable can return a value. 
Is there any something wrong with my preparestatement or setstring ?

Comment: Please post your error.  You didn't declare the type of `sql` ie `String sql = ...`

Comment: my error is SQL return without NIP variable. SetString doesn't set the NIP value.

Comment: @user1875301 Add a `catch` exception block before `finally` statement and print the exception in order to find out what caused the error.

Comment: @user1875301 is NIP column in your table is of type varchar???

Comment: "SQL return without NIP..." - Are you printing the sql statement and expecting ? to be replaced with nip value?

Comment: @PrasadKhode yes, NIP column is varchar..

Comment: @user1875301 ok so wat is ur problem? is ur Resultset is empty?? did you tried to run the same query in ur sql prompt and what result u get??

Comment: @PrasadKhode thanks prasad and all, problem was solved.. I have the wrong column..